# Inverse of ordering function

Tags: order-statistics, matrix-inverse

Lets assume we have p by n matrix.We can generate an output matrix, w (p x p) such as w_ij represent how many times i_th rows number is bigger than j_th (can be at most n obviously).

My question is if we are given w matrix(again w_ij represent how many times i_th row is bigger than j_th row) such that n is fixed, it means any w_ij + w_ji = n except i=j. Can we generate that p x n matrix.

A small example

If the input data is

```
dat <- matrix(1:9, 3)
dat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    7
#[2,]    2    5    8
#[3,]    3    6    9
```

the expected outcome is

```
W
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    0    0
#[2,]    3    0    0
#[3,]    3    3    0
```

Comment: Given the w matrix and a fixed value of n, surely the p by n matrix is not unique. Do you wish to find a (non-unique) such p by n matrix corresponding to w?

Comment: It is not one to one mapping to get w but many to one. Like some range might be around ~1000 but some ~0.01. you can choose the range what I want is to find an algorithm to get the data from w